# Cut the square cloth!

Tags: mathematics, geometry

> I have a square cloth with side length $x$ cm, and I am going to cut it into at least $n$ squares with side length $1$ cm for my customer, and also you cannot cut the cloth to thinner pieces (reminded by @risky mysteries). I cannot glue any bits of cloth together. What is the minimum value of $x$?

---

Problem inspired from a math test problem in my school (about a month ago).

---

Thanks to @Jaap Scherphuis, I now know this is an unsolved problem. So of course I still haven't solved it. You can use a computer!

Comment: Is folding valid?

Comment: @riskymysteries Yes, but you can't say a $1$ by $1.1$ rectangle is a $1$ by $1$ square with folding. You need to cut it.

Comment: *cut it into at least n squares*, no wasting anything, right?

Comment: @riskymysteries You can have some cloth left.

Comment: Is 1 a valid number for n?

Comment: @riskymysteries Of course!

Comment: Just to make this clear, so is this $x$ should be defined in term of $n$ a.k.a $x = f(n)$?

Comment: Isn't this an open problem in mathematics? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_packing_in_a_square

Comment: This isn't clear: the problem is *inspired* from a math test problem, but has not been solved by the OP. So there is no definitive answer? This should be closed IMO.

Answer (score 1):

> $\lceil\sqrt{n}\;\rceil$ 
>  (the ceiling of the square root of n)

Because

> If you need *n* squares which are 1cm wide, you essentially require a piece of cloth with an area of *n²*, i.e. a square of length √n. 
>  But given you can't glue pieces together we take the ceiling of √n to ensure we have enough pieces whose length are 1cm

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, $x \geq \sqrt n$, otherwise your original square would have less area than the n smaller squares.

> In most cases, you will need $x = \lceil \sqrt n \rceil$, as that will be the smallest square that allows you to cut the necessary pieces.

However, for $n=5$,

> You can make do with $x = 2\sqrt2$:
>  [image: Square with diagonal smaller squares]
>  This wastes 3 units, which is less than would be wasted for a size 3 square.

> This does not continue to work for higher $n$.  For example, for $x=3\sqrt2$, you could fit 13 squares in a similar pattern, but the slightly smaller $x = 4$ would have room for 16.

So, in conclusion,

> you need $x = \lceil \sqrt n \rceil$, except for $n=5$, where $x=2\sqrt 2$ will work.

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer

> 1

Reason:

> The cloth can be cut into 2 pieces like this
>  
>  
>  [image]

Comment: No, you cannot cut it to thinner pieces. I will add that.

Comment: @CulverKwan Make sure to acknowledge the edit!

Comment: Ok, I have acknowledge it!

Answer (score -3):

In both the square, area will be the same.

suppose big square has area, A = x*x

all small square total area will be A = n * 1 *1

so,
x*x = n * 1 * 1

x = √n, for all x>=n

Comment: How can you cut for example 2 whole squares from a piece of cloth of size $\sqrt{2}\times\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: i think solution will work for all x>=n

Comment: You already said that $x=\sqrt{n}$, so how can it be that $x\ge n$?